# Favicon is not working properly

Tags: web, icons, favicon

I am trying to add flavicon to my web, I tried

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />`

Now there is icon with logo of my webhosting company.
Here is web u can show code and find problem. http://nexgea.com

Comment: You need to hard refresh your browser, because your favicon is coming just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning your webbrowser cache.
Or try

```
CTRL + F5
```

I had the same problem a half year ago and this worked for me

[image: What I see]

This is what I see...

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to clear your browser cache